# How can I manage background tasks in FastAPI?

Tags: multiprocessing, fastapi

I am creating a FastAPI application that is collecting user data in the background 24/7 and saving it to the DB. The API communicates with the data collector and I want it to be able to use multiple processes.

I was wondering:
How would I go about implementing something like this in a multi-worker environemnt? Because I don't want the data collection task and discord bot to run in every process, but I also need to access the data throughout the API.

I learned that FastAPI has a BackgroundTask functionality, but that doesn't suit my need either.

Do I have to use some inter-proccess-communication? If so, what do you recommend?

Comment: If you deploy a fastapi app with an async route (and non blocking i/o) and use a worker manager like [uvicorn][1] you will be able to paralelize api endpoint calls.

But it imply that your data collector can also handle parallel calls.

can you be more specific about "I don't want the data collection task and discord bot to run in every process'"?


  [1]: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/server-workers/